# Related Territory object field not fetched with the fields of User Territory Association object. (child to parent relationship query)

Tags: soql

My query goes like :

```
SELECT Id, Territory.TerritoryName__c
FROM UserTerritory2Association
WHERE Territory.TerritoryName__c = 'ABC'
```

I tried using `Territory2.TerritoryName__c`, `Territory__r.TerritoryName__c`, `Territory2__r.TerritoryName__c`

But all of these queries show errors like:

> Didn't understand relationship Territory.TerritoryName__c

I think User, Territory are the parent objects for the junction object - User Territory Association. How do I get the correct relationship name?

Comment: The [SOAP API documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_userterritory2association.htm) says that the relationship field is `Territory2Id`, which _should_ mean that `Territory2.TerritoryName__c` is correct. Have you replaced both instances of `Territory.TerritoryName__c` in your query? Replacing only one would still give you an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Confirmed this query works:

```
SELECT Territory2Id, UserId, RoleInTerritory2, IsActive
FROM UserTerritory2Association
WHERE User.Name = 'ABC'
AND Territory2.Name = 'ABC'
// (can use User or Territory2)
```

```
Territory2.Name = Territory Label
Territory2.DeveloperName = Territory Name
```